# Fill a multidimensional array with pairs of ordered values

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I have to present 16 financial products in a 4x4 matrix on a website. The matrix replaces the representation of a scatter graph, where the returns of the product are represented in the X axis and the risk in the Y (they are simply pairs of values), so the product in the lowest left place are the one with the minor risk and the minor returns and the ones in the top right are the ones with the major risk and the major return.
To reach this result, I thought of putting the products in a multidimensional 4x4 array, but I don't know how to sort the pairs of values correctly.
I tried some sorting methods but nobody gave me the required result.

Here is an Exammple of what I want to obtain:
Taking this sixteen couple of values:
(3,5)-(2,8)-(7,3)-(4,9)-(3,2)-(4,10)-(6,2)-(1,4)-(5,2)-(8,9)-(7,11)-(10,12)-(3,11)-(5,10)-(2,16)-(9,15)

I would like to show it in the matrix in this order

```
Y
^
|(7,3)(8,9)(10,12)(9,15)
|(5,2)(6,2)(5,10)(7,11)
|(3,2)(3,5)(4,9)(4,10)
|(1,4)(2,8)(3,11)(2,16)
|_____________________>X
```

Comment: Consider the matrix like ia Scatter/bubble chart. The lower left contains lower values, and the upper right the highest. I need to understand how to distribute these values in a 4x4 matrix. (and find a function for this kind of sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer because the first one and its comments are before you added an example and that answer was way off.

Your example is helpful.  It looks like the first value in your pair is Y and the second is X?  If so, that's opposite normal convention.

It seems your unspoken rules for arrangement are to arrange the pairs in such a way that the Y (left) values are increasing upward in each column, and the X (right) values are increasing rightward in each row.  Importantly, it seems for Y values the columns are otherwise independent, and for the X values the rows are otherwise independent.  Independent meaning you don't care about absolute placement from position to position.  Like for Y, you don't care that a 3 in the third column is lower than the 3 in the first column.

But these rules will still produce multiple valid result sets.  For example, in your example, (7,3) and (6,2) can be swapped and the rules as outlined above still apply.

If these unspoken rules are correct, try this broad approach:

**(1) Put the list into a matrix, (2) sort all of the columns, (3) sort all of the rows, (4) repeat sorting columns and rows a few times.**

Here is some code to illustrate this.  Because this is just a 4x4 matrix, efficiency isn't important.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Tuple<int,int>[] pairs = {
        Tuple.Create(3, 5),
        Tuple.Create(2, 8),
        Tuple.Create(7, 3),
        Tuple.Create(4, 9),
        Tuple.Create(3, 2),
        Tuple.Create(4, 10),
        Tuple.Create(6, 2),
        Tuple.Create(1, 4),
        Tuple.Create(5, 2),
        Tuple.Create(8, 9),
        Tuple.Create(7, 11),
        Tuple.Create(10, 12),
        Tuple.Create(3, 11),
        Tuple.Create(5, 10),
        Tuple.Create(2, 16),
        Tuple.Create(9, 15)             
    };

    var matrix = load(pairs); //Put data into a 4x4 matrix, order doesn't matter

    Console.WriteLine("Original input:");
    print(matrix);

    matrix = sort(matrix);

    Console.WriteLine("Ordered output:");
    print(matrix);
}

private static Tuple<int,int>[,] load(Tuple<int,int>[] pairs) {
    var rv = new Tuple<int, int>[4, 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            rv[i, j] = pairs[i * 4 + j];
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

private static Tuple<int, int>[, ] sort(Tuple<int, int>[,] matrix) {
    var rv = matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        rv = orderCols(rv);
        rv = orderRows(rv);
    }
    return rv;
}

private static Tuple<int,int>[,] orderCols(Tuple<int,int>[,] matrix) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        //Convert column to 1D array, sort it, then apply it back
        Tuple<int, int>[] a = new Tuple<int, int>[4];
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) a[r] = matrix[r, c];
        a = a.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item1).ToArray();
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) matrix[r, c] = a[r];
    }
    return matrix;
}

private static Tuple<int,int>[,] orderRows(Tuple<int,int>[,] matrix) {
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        //Convert row to 1D array, sort it, then apply it back
        Tuple<int, int>[] a = new Tuple<int, int>[4];
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) a[c] = matrix[r, c];
        a = a.OrderBy(t => t.Item2).ToArray();
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) matrix[r, c] = a[c];
    }
    return matrix;
}

private static void print(Tuple<int, int>[,] matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            Console.Write(writeTuple(matrix[i, j]));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private static string writeTuple(Tuple<int, int> t) {
    var a = t.Item1.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' ');
    var b = t.Item2.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' ');
    return String.Format("({0}, {1})  ", a, b);
}
```

Output:

```
Original input:
( 3,  5)  ( 2,  8)  ( 7,  3)  ( 4,  9)  
( 3,  2)  ( 4, 10)  ( 6,  2)  ( 1,  4)  
( 5,  2)  ( 8,  9)  ( 7, 11)  (10, 12)  
( 3, 11)  ( 5, 10)  ( 2, 16)  ( 9, 15)  

Ordered output:
( 6,  2)  ( 7,  3)  ( 8,  9)  (10, 12)  
( 5,  2)  ( 4,  9)  ( 7, 11)  ( 9, 15)  
( 3,  2)  ( 3,  5)  ( 5, 10)  ( 4, 10)  
( 1,  4)  ( 2,  8)  ( 3, 11)  ( 2, 16)
```

As you can see, the output does not match your example output exactly, but it is valid per the rules you seem to want.  Depending on the ordering of the input, the output will be different because there are multiple valid result sets.  If I'm wrong in any assumptions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Eric, your solution is very smart and 99% perfect. What I needed was to represent in a matrix what is usually represented in a scatter graph, with the necessary approximations that the solution of the matrix imposes. The only more control that your solution suggested me to do, is a further ordering when it is verified that two values of the pairs are equal (in your example the pairs (5,10) and (4,10) that must be reversed to be sorted correctly.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, additional rules could be added to the sort() method.  The reason behind your rule isn't clear to me (5-10 and 4-10 are not adjacent in your example) but hopefully my code can get you the rest of the way.  Good luck!  This was a fun challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your problem, it seems to me you need to sort your collection linearly (1-dimensional), and then present it (2-dimensional).  There's a distinction between data storage and data presentation.  Here's what I came up with:

```
//Sample data to work with
var products = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", 12));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", 23));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", 62));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", 17));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("E", 11));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("F", 75));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("G", 95));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("H", 24));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("I", 85));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("J", 41));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("K", 76));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("L", 77));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("M", 33));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("N", 81));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("O", 34));
products.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("P", 45));

//Sort the collection
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ordered = products.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();

//Put linear results into 2D array (4x4)
var matrix = new KeyValuePair<string, int>[4,4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        matrix[i, j] = ordered[i * 4 + j];

//Write out results
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var c = ordered[i * 4 + j];
        Console.Write(c.Key + ": " + c.Value.ToString() + "    ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
E: 11    A: 12    D: 17    B: 23    
H: 24    M: 33    O: 34    J: 41    
P: 45    C: 62    F: 75    K: 76    
L: 77    N: 81    I: 85    G: 95
```

Comment: Note, my example dumps the linear data into the console which needs line breaks, but since you are outputting to the web, you may not need line breaks (<br>) if you format the display correctly with CSS.  If each cell is { display: inline-block; width: 25% }, it will wrap automatically into a grid.  CSS flexbox would be an even better candidate.

Comment: may be you need to sort by y.value as well.

Comment: Hello Eric, like miller says, I need to sort evaluating the pairs of values, reproducing a scatter chart in a 4x4 matrix. I put an explanation on my question, because should not be clear

Comment: Aah, the scatter plot part wasn't clear to me.  Unfortunately, your problem still is not clear to me.  Perhaps someone else can help.  Perhaps if you posted sample data and the expected output, the solution would be clearer.  For instance, do you know how to produce the desired output if 15 of the values are clustered to the bottom-left and one value is at the top right?  How would you display that into a 4x4 matrix?  Once you establish some rules, the solution should be easier to solve.